# Age in years month and day in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

The question is to find age of a person in years, months and days using sql queries. For example:

```
If date of birth = 2000-07-03 (yyyy-mm-dd)
and current date = 2021-09-08 (yyyy-mm-dd)
Then the my age  = 21 years 2 months 5 days
```

I have seen similar question on internet, but their solutions have used inbuilt function like DATEADD,DATEDIFF(interval,date1,date2) and so on which are not available in lower versions of sql.

So how can we implement these functions from scratch. I tried to write some queries for the same. I am getting correct number of years and months but i am getting wrong number of days.

Schema of student table(Name,DOB)

```
mysql>select DOB,
    ->floor(datediff(curdate(),DOB)/365.25)as years,
    ->abs(floor(datediff(curdate(),DOB)/365.25)*12 - timestampdiff(month,DOB,curdate()))as months,
    ->extract(day from curdate())-extract(day from DOB) as days from student;


+------------+-------+--------+------+
| dob        | years | months | day  |
+------------+-------+--------+------+
| 2001-08-03 |    20 |      1 |    5 |
| 2001-10-04 |    19 |     11 |    4 |
| 2001-11-25 |    19 |      9 |  -17 |  // correct answer- 19years 9months 14 days
+------------------------------------+
```

How can i correct this?

Comment: What do you mean by *lower versions of sql*?

Comment: I am using sql 8.0 and DATEADD function is not working on that. So by lower I mean sql versions lower than 8.0.

Comment: What is sql 8.0? Do you mean MySql 8.0?

Comment: oh yes, mysql 8.0. pardon me for the confusion

Comment: In MySql there is DATE_ADD(): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: Yes, It helped a lot ! Thanks !